# Translate code from Java to .NET

Tags: c#, java, .net, translation, equivalent

I need to translate this fragment from Java to .NET (rather C#, but I know Visual Basic too).
This is code:

```
typeStrings = new Dictionary<Int16, String>();

    Field[] fields = Type.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            typeStrings.put(field.getInt(null), field.getName());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

First line (Dictionary class) is from .NET (my translation try ;)).
I know the Field class is from java.lang.reflect.Field, but I couldn't found .NET equivalent.
Kind regards!

Comment: `Int16` isn't a type in Java and you can't cast it from `int` automagically.  Can you update your example so it would compile in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var typeStrings = new Dictionary<int, string>();

FieldInfo[] fields = yourObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    typeStrings.Add((int)field.GetValue(yourObject), field.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the `System.Reflection.FieldInfo` class and `typeof(SomeType).GetFields()`.

Answer (score 1):

try to do this

```
    var typeStrings = new Dictionary<Int16, String>();

    var fields = this.GetType().GetFields();

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        try
        {
            typeStrings.Add(Convert.ToInt16(field.FieldHandle.Value.ToInt32().ToString()), field.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `catch` block is useless.

Comment: I know ,i just wanted to show catching in c# ,also converting returns same result